# BorderRadius on Parent reveals hidden parts of Children

Tags: css, nativescript

consider these there layers :

blue: 350x350;

red: 300x300;

green: 200x200 !!;

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="350" height="350" background="blue" >

    <AbsoluteLayout width="300" height="300" left=25 top=25 background="red" >

        <AbsoluteLayout width="200" height="200" left=-120 top=-120 background="green"  >


        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

it is looks like:

[image]

now just add border-radius to the red layer,

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="350" height="350" background="blue" >

    <AbsoluteLayout width="300" height="300" left=25 top=25 background="red" borderRadius=300 >

        <AbsoluteLayout width="200" height="200" left=-120 top=-120 background="green"  >


        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

the result:

[image]

what should I do??

I am expecting this one: (generated by fair same code and css structure in html)

[image]

to making the question more vivid:
if I cancel clipToBound property (equivalent to overFlow:hidden) I will get this one as it would be expected:

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting the output should look like?  What you show makes sense to me.

Comment: @David I added a picture that demonstrates what I am expecting.

Comment: Try overflow:hidden style in the parent, it won't display the children.

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy   There is no overflow property available in {N} but we use clipToBounds, and thats working right now , pay attention to the negative values of top and left in green box!

Comment: Check this.  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2274

Comment: @vcs as I mentioned clipToBounds is working here, but it neglects to apply clipToBounds effect on the space between parent and child!
The link that you provided here is suggesting to add a feature to set clipToBounds as false,  but I am saying even when it is set as true (by default) it won't work properly. (just see 4th fig. it is what in the link that you provided asking for, and it works. what I am referring to is something else)